# Word for "appropriate" as in dress code etc

Tags: words, usage

I'm wondering how to ask a superior what the appropriate dress code is, for example: "what is the *appropriate* attire to wear on my first day? (of work etc)."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> Word for “appropriate” as in dress code etc.

How about [適切]{てきせつ}な, ふさわしい, as in 「適切な[服装]{ふくそう}」「ふさわしい服装」

> "what is the appropriate attire to wear on my first day? (of work etc)."

I would say:
「[初日]{しょにち}はどんな服装が｛よい・よろしい・ふさわしい・適切｝でしょうか？」
「初日はどんな服装で行けばよいでしょうか？」

In case you want to sound a bit more casual:
「初日はどんな[格好]{かっこう}で行けばいいですか？」

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the natural/formal way a Japanese person would ask it would be:

> 服装{ふくそう}の[決まり]{きまり}はありますか？
>   *fukusō no kimari wa arimasu ka*